# 32 bit or 16 bit textures

Tags: 2d, textures

I'm trying to build some 2d character with Photoshop and Spine. By now, I have created some of my characters using 16 bit color depth images in Photoshop. Now, I wonder whether I have to use 32 bit or just create everything with 16 bit textures...
How much does it affect my game? Considering a 2D Unity or Flash game.

Comment: memory usage mostly

Comment: Is "16-bit" in Photoshop per channel or total for the image? Same question for "32-bit".

Comment: it is in Photoshop not total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a lower number of bits per pixel means you save filesize, loading time and texture memory. Also, sprite drawing will be faster because less data needs to be moved between graphic memory sections.

When you develop a 2d game and your target devices are desktop PCs, these factors can usually be ignored as any modern PC should handle 32bit graphics with ease. However, when you develop for less powerful devices, like low-end smartphones, these optimizations can matter. Not only do smartphones have much weaker hardware, many smartphone users have data-plans with very harsh traffic limitations. These users are reluctant to download apps which are several MB in size, so any trick to get the filesize down can result in more downloads (although when you use Unity, you already lost that battle, because the Unity mobile runtime alone is already almost 10MB in size).

Whether or not there will be a *visual* difference depends on your graphic style. With a retro pixel-art style, reducing the bit-depth is often completely invisible, even when you go as low as 256 colors. With graphics which are rasterized from rendered 3d models, it can be very visible. You will also have problems with any color gradients.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Unity to compress your textures on import and set this per texture and/or globally so you're free to create your assets at a higher quality.

You can then play with the settings, leaving your source assets as is. They'll be compressed when you build the game.